# Dollar ($) sign after activity class name in Android logs (non-anonymous inner class)

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am going through some crash logs for my app and the stack trace shows something like :

```
at MyActivity.formatDouble(MyActivity.java:182)
at MyActivity.access$47(MyActivity.java:196)    
at MyActivity$28.onCameraChange(MyActivity.java:167)
```

"MyActivity" is an activity and hence not an anonymous inner class. I can't be sure of the dollar sign on line#3 (and the one in line#2 also)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that line 167 is within an anonymous class *within* `MyActivity`, and that `access$47` is simply a trampoline method to allow `onCameraChange` to call a private method within `MyActivity`. (The JVM wouldn't allow that, so the Java compiler creates a method to allow it.)

You can see this easily with a simple Java class not even on Android:

```
public class Test {

    private static void privateMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                privateMethod();
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

This gives a stack trace similar to the one you've shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
        at Test.privateMethod(Test.java:4)
        at Test.access$000(Test.java:1)
        at Test$1.run(Test.java:10)
        at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

The `Test$1.run` is within an anonymous inner class within `main`, and the `access$000` method is providing access to `privateMethod`.

Comment: Thank you ! Just curious though, what do the numbers $1 (in your example) and $28 (in mine) denote ? The number of instances of that class currently in memory.. ?

Comment: @EasyAndSlow: No, they can't do that - because they're part of the compile-time data. I believe they're implementation-specific... probably the number of the anonymous class within that class (in which case you have a lot of anonymous classes...)